# How can I remove characters in parentheses from file names?

Tags: bash, shell, text

I have a list of file names of the form:

```
Filename (region).gba
```

And I would like to rename them all without the `(region)` tag.

How can I do this using standard command line tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
for f in *'('*')'*; do mv -i "$f" "${f/(*)/}"; done
```

Or, for those who prefer their commands spread out over multiple lines:

```
for f in *'('*')'*
do
   mv -i "$f" "${f/(*)/}"
done
```

#### How it works

- `for f in *'('*')'*; do`

  This starts a loop over all files whose names contain `(` followed by `)`.
- `mv -i "$f" "${f/(*)/}"`

  This renames those files removing the parens and everything between the parens.

  `"${f/(*)/}"` is an example of a shell feature called *pattern substitution*.  It looks for an occurrence of the glob `(*)` and replaces it with an empty string.  See `man bash` for more details.

  The `-i` option tells `mv` not to overwrite a target file without asking.  This is optional.  You may prefer to make a backup copy instead.  See `man mv` for more options.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

#### Example

Let's start in a directory with these files:

```
$ ls -1
Filename (region) 2.gba
Filename (region).gba
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ for f in *'('*')'*; do mv -i "$f" "${f//(*)/}"; done
```

After our command, the files have these names:

```
$ ls -1
Filename  2.gba
Filename .gba
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to solve this problem.

```
ls * | sed 's/\(.*\) \([(].*[)]\).*/mv "\1 \2.gba" "\1.gba"/g'
```

This will list the `mv` commands to move the files. Pipe through `sh` or `bash` to actually execute.

To explain:

1. `ls *` lists the files in the directory
2. `sed` will edit the incoming strings.
3. `'s/` begins a substitution
4. `\(.*\)` matches the non-region part of the file name, in capture group 1
5. `\([(].*[)]\).*` matches the remainder of the file name, except the extension
6. `/mv "\1 \2.ext" "\1.ext"/g'` composes the `mv` command and ends the substitution.

Comment: You shouldn't parse `ls` (might have a newline) but seems to work for your dataset. When you replave `ext` with `gba` and the `sed` global flag `g` with `e`, the commands are executed. `ls *gba| sed 's/\(.*\) \([(].*[)]\).*/mv "\1 \2.gba" "\1.gba"/e'`

Comment: `ls` is not guaranteed to produce valid file names in its output.  There is some discussion of this here:  [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  This is official policy: the purpose of `ls`, according to the programs authors, is to be ["a tool for direct consumption by a human" and, consequently, they will not add any options to make `ls` useful in scripts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2014-02/msg00005.html)